# JGit - Get all commits (PlotCommitList) that affected a file/path

Tags: filter, path, commit, jgit

Hy i am trying to get all the commits that include a specific directory or file of my repository.

I tried the folowing code :

```
public PlotCommitList getPlotCommits(String path){
    System.out.println(path);
    PlotCommitList<PlotLane> plotCommitList = new PlotCommitList<PlotLane>();
    PlotWalk revWalk = new PlotWalk(repository);
    try {

        ObjectId rootId = repository.resolve("HEAD");
        if (rootId != null) {
            RevCommit root = revWalk.parseCommit(rootId);
            revWalk.markStart(root);
            revWalk.setTreeFilter(PathFilter.create(path));
            plotCommitList.source(revWalk);
            plotCommitList.fillTo(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            return plotCommitList;
        }

    } catch (AmbiguousObjectException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GitRepository.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GitRepository.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return plotCommitList;
}
```

I don't get just the commits that affected that file. I get some "subLists" of the entire list but not just those commits that affected that file.

Maybe TreeFilter doesn't work how i think? I should use other way to get those commits?
I saw the log command has a path filter but i didn't tried it yet because it returns a RevCommit list and for my PlotCommitList i need a revwalk to use as a source. And also i think i cannot cast RevCommit to PlotCommit.

A guy had the same problem here (1st Answer with fileA and fileB issue) : [Link - Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777453/looping-over-commits-for-a-file-with-jgit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to combine the `PathFilter` with an `ANY_DIFF` filter:

```
revWalk.setTreeFilter(
    AndTreeFilter.create(PathFilter.create(path), TreeFilter.ANY_DIFF));
```

With only PathFilter I think what happens is that all commits are selected where the specified tree exists (e.g. all commits starting from the initial commit of that file).

Also see the [API docs of setTreeFilter](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.1.0.201209190230-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevWalk.html#setTreeFilter%28org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.filter.TreeFilter%29) or how the [LogCommand](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/stable-5.4/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/LogCommand.java#L137-L138) does it.

Comment: It works like a charm, i was such a dumb! That was so simple, and also documented. Thank you for the tip.