# JGit: How to get all commits of a branch? (Without changes to the working directory ...)

Tags: java, jgit

how do I get all commits of a branch with JGit, without changing the working directory?

Unfortunately the JGit docs are not very good ...

In ruby with grit it is very easy:

```
repo = Grit::Repo.new(pathToRepo)

repo.commits(branchName, false).each do |commit|
    doSomethingWithTheCommit
end
```

Bye,
hurik

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tried this here first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13925765/2246865

But it wasn't was working always, so I found this here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/280339/

Here my solution, it isn't really nice, but it's working ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
    Repository repo = new FileRepository("pathToRepo/.git");
    Git git = new Git(repo);
    RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo);

    List<Ref> branches = git.branchList().call();

    for (Ref branch : branches) {
        String branchName = branch.getName();

        System.out.println("Commits of branch: " + branch.getName());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

        Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call();

        for (RevCommit commit : commits) {
            boolean foundInThisBranch = false;

            RevCommit targetCommit = walk.parseCommit(repo.resolve(
                    commit.getName()));
            for (Map.Entry<String, Ref> e : repo.getAllRefs().entrySet()) {
                if (e.getKey().startsWith(Constants.R_HEADS)) {
                    if (walk.isMergedInto(targetCommit, walk.parseCommit(
                            e.getValue().getObjectId()))) {
                        String foundInBranch = e.getValue().getName();
                        if (branchName.equals(foundInBranch)) {
                            foundInThisBranch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (foundInThisBranch) {
                System.out.println(commit.getName());
                System.out.println(commit.getAuthorIdent().getName());
                System.out.println(new Date(commit.getCommitTime() * 1000L));
                System.out.println(commit.getFullMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have problem with this solution that it takes about five minutes to finnish on my quite large repo.

Comment: Please try some other solutions which are posted here.

Answer (score 17):

With the code below you can get **all commits of a branch or tag**:

```
Repository repository = new FileRepository("/path/to/repository/.git");
String treeName = "refs/heads/master"; // tag or branch
for (RevCommit commit : git.log().add(repository.resolve(treeName)).call()) {
    System.out.println(commit.getName());
}
```

The varialbe `treeName` will define the tag or branch. This `treeName` is the complete name of the branch or tag, for example `refs/heads/master` for the *master* branch or `refs/tags/v1.0` for a tag called *v1.0*.

Alternatively, you can use the [gitective](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/gitective) API. The following code does the same as the code above:

```
Repository repository = new FileRepository("/path/to/repository/.git");

AndCommitFilter filters = new AndCommitFilter();
CommitListFilter revCommits = new CommitListFilter();
filters.add(revCommits);

CommitFinder finder = new CommitFinder(repository);
finder.setFilter(filters);
String treeName = "refs/heads/master"; // tag or branch
finder.findFrom(treeName);

for (RevCommit commit : revCommits) {
    System.out.println(commit.getName());
}
```

Some try/catch will be necessary, I hide them to make the code shorter.
Good luck.

Comment: Will this work if the branch has a merge from more than 1 other branch/ commit?

Comment: Glad that my solution worked for you @tgkprog. If want some examples code to help you with jgit I would recommend you take a look at this repository https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook.

Answer (score 4):

I was just looking for a way to list all commits under each branch and I found this thread. I finally did something a bit different from some of the answers I found here and worked.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
    Repository repo = new FileRepository("pathToRepo/.git");
    Git git = new Git(repo);

    List<Ref> branches = git.branchList().call();

    for (Ref branch : branches) {
        String branchName = branch.getName();

        System.out.println("Commits of branch: " + branchName);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

        Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().add(repo.resolve(branchName)).call();

        List<RevCommit> commitsList = Lists.newArrayList(commits.iterator());

        for (RevCommit commit : commitsList) {
            System.out.println(commit.getName());
            System.out.println(commit.getAuthorIdent().getName());
            System.out.println(new Date(commit.getCommitTime() * 1000L));
            System.out.println(commit.getFullMessage());
        }
    }

    git.close();
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the docs *should* really be better.

You could use the [JGit Log command](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#LogCommand_.28git-log.29) or use a library like [gitective](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/gitective) which makes iterating over commits easy. You can look at the source to learn more about JGit.

Other (more complicated) ways are described in [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777453/looping-over-commits-for-a-file-with-jgit).

Answer (score 0):

A much shorter and clean solution can be done via the "log" command that JGit provides:

```
    Repository repository = new FileRepository("pathToRepo/.git");
    logs = new Git(repository).log()
            .add(repository.resolve("remotes/origin/testbranch"))
            .call();
    count = 0;
    for (RevCommit rev : logs) {
        System.out.println("Commit: " + rev /* + ", name: " + rev.getName() + ", id: " + rev.getId().getName() */);
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Had " + count + " commits overall on test-branch");
```

See the [full snippet](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowLog.java) at the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook)

Comment: When I do this for my branch I see commits on it and master.  When use master I see only its commits.  I expect "--stop-on-copy" behavior but that's not what I'm seeing with   git.log().add(git.repository.resolve("refs/heads/mybranch")).call()

Comment: Ok, then the addRange() option listed in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35327138/411846 should work.

Comment: Thanks.  I figure I need to get head of branch and walk back until I find a RevCommit where all parents are from another branch.  Any commit along the way may have multiple parents from other branches but a commit with only a parent from another branch must be beginning of branch.

Comment: How do I figure out what branch I'm on and from what branch it came?  I can get HEAD then look for it on all branches but I don't know how to find origin of my branche

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but I thought add(ObjectId branch) to provide a gate to the active branch, but I appear to require a range

```
Git git = ...
ObjectId master = git.repository.resolve("refs/heads/master")
ObjectId branch = git.repository.resolve("refs/heads/mybranch")

git.log().addRange(master,branch).call()
```