# How to get git informations with Java?

Tags: java, git

Is there any way to retrieve git information programmatically using Java? I would like to know:

1. All branches in current repository-directory
2. Current branch of my working project
3. All committed informations

In addition can I execute git processes (commit, rollback, checkout, delete branch, etc.) using Java?

I really do appreciate any suggestions .. Thanks

Comment: look into jgit : http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15822544/6309

Comment: @VonC , are you also would like to suggest to use jgit : eclipse.org/jgit ? Thanks for your useful link ..

Comment: Yes, JGit seems the main solution to access Git repo from Java.

Comment: @VonC I had also found http://javagit.sourceforge.net/cookbook.php .This also a nice and lightweight lib. :-)

Comment: @Cataclysm but certainly not as recent and up-to-date as JGit ;) 2008 vs most recent commit yesterday (https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/commits/master

Comment: @VonC if possible I would like to use with simple java codes without import any third party libs. :-)

Answer (score 4):

JGit http://eclipse.org/jgit/ is a Java API for interacting with a Git repository.  I believe it is the basis of EGit which is the plug-in that integrates Eclipse to Git.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can make use of shell commands within Java. Try to run a simple shell command withing Java. Then you can add more git specific commands within your program.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/